# Minecraft Error Report

Tags: 12.04, minecraft

Today I tried the first time to start Minecraft (with OpenJDK 6 Runtime) in ubuntu 12.04,
but when the mojang-screen should come this Error-Report appears:

```
--- BEGIN ERROR REPORT b5666078 --------
Generated 14.08.12 22:58

- Minecraft Version: 1.3.1
- Operating System: Linux (amd64) version 3.2.0-23-generic
- Java Version: 1.6.0_24, Sun Microsystems Inc.
- Java VM Version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Sun Microsystems Inc.
- Memory: 50558552 bytes (48 MB) / 77856768 bytes (74 MB) up to 915341312 bytes (872 MB)
- JVM Flags: 0 total; 
- LWJGL: 2.4.2
- OpenGL: ~ERROR~ NullPointerException: null
- Is Modded: Probably not
- Type: Client
- Texture Pack: ~ERROR~ NullPointerException: null
- Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)[failed to get system properties (java.lang.NullPointerException)]


org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not init GLX
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.initDefaultPeerInfo(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.<init>(LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.createPeerInfo(LinuxDisplay.java:684)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:854)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:784)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:765)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.a(SourceFile:233)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(SourceFile:516)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
--- END ERROR REPORT 82b5e9f9 ----------
```

Please Help! Im getting desperate.

Answer (score 0):

Please open the terminal and run this commands:

> lspci |grep VGA
>
> dmesg |grep NVIDIA
>
> glxinfo | grep direct

Put the output so we can see.

This seems an issue with your graphic card

Comment: lspci |grep VGA
00:0d.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C61 [GeForce 7025 / nForce 630a] (rev a2)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Redwood PRO [Radeon HD 5500 Series]

 
dmesg |grep NVIDIA
[   11.944783] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[   14.034177] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  173.14.35  Fri Jun  8 00:07:59 PDT 2012

Comment: at glxinfo | grep direct it says, that the application glxinfo is not installed.

Comment: That could be it. You need to have GLX enabled to be able to play that game. Install the proprietary drivers. Also i would advise you to try switching to Sun Java to see if that solves your problem.